# JBoss Deployement Issue - Cannot deploy this Jar

Tags: jpa, jboss, ejb, jms

I am trying to deploy an application in jBoss and I'm getting this issue. I am trying to deploy a jar and I'm getting the issue.

Attached complete log:

```
jboss@ubuntu:/usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin$ ./standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

  JAVA: java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml

=========================================================================

20:01:39,863 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
20:01:40,029 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
20:01:40,071 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
20:01:40,724 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
20:01:40,726 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
20:01:40,735 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
20:01:40,741 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
20:01:40,765 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
20:01:40,770 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
20:01:40,784 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
20:01:40,786 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS016300: Activating JacORB Subsystem
20:01:40,807 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
20:01:40,810 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
20:01:40,815 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
20:01:40,816 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
20:01:40,821 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
20:01:40,828 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
20:01:40,878 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
20:01:40,887 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
20:01:40,901 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
20:01:40,928 INFO  [org.jboss.jaxr] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS014000: Started JAXR subsystem, binding JAXR connection factory into JNDI as: java:jboss/jaxr/ConnectionFactory
20:01:40,988 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-14) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
20:01:41,013 WARN  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-12) JBAS011600: AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO. If your platform is Linux, install LibAIO to enable the AIO journal
20:01:41,031 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-6) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080
20:01:41,062 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-10) live server is starting with configuration HornetQ Configuration (clustered=false,backup=false,sharedStore=true,journalDirectory=/usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/data/messagingjournal,bindingsDirectory=/usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/data/messagingbindings,largeMessagesDirectory=/usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/data/messaginglargemessages,pagingDirectory=/usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/data/messagingpaging)
20:01:41,067 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-10) Waiting to obtain live lock
20:01:41,124 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.persistence.impl.journal.JournalStorageManager] (MSC service thread 1-10) Using NIO Journal
20:01:41,186 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBAS016330: CORBA ORB Service started
20:01:41,275 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar"
20:01:41,277 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments
20:01:41,279 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015014: Re-attempting failed deployment postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar
20:01:41,281 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
20:01:41,282 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS016328: CORBA Naming Service started
20:01:41,282 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-14) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:4447
20:01:41,350 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager] (MSC service thread 1-10) Waiting to obtain live lock
20:01:41,350 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager] (MSC service thread 1-10) Live Server Obtained live lock
20:01:41,518 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-16) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
20:01:41,578 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-14) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.2)
20:01:41,589 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/LoggerDS]
20:01:41,783 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptor] (MSC service thread 1-10) Started Netty Acceptor version 3.2.5.Final-a96d88c localhost:5445 for CORE protocol
20:01:41,784 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptor] (MSC service thread 1-10) Started Netty Acceptor version 3.2.5.Final-a96d88c localhost:5455 for CORE protocol
20:01:41,785 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-10) Server is now live
20:01:41,786 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-10) HornetQ Server version 2.2.13.Final (HQ_2_2_13_FINAL_AS7, 122) [26df2dd3-96ba-11e2-a76d-685d436e1847]) started
20:01:41,789 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-4) trying to deploy queue jms.queue.demo
20:01:41,825 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/demo
20:01:41,841 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
20:01:41,842 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/RemoteConnectionFactory
20:01:41,843 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-3) trying to deploy queue jms.queue.loggerQueue
20:01:41,844 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/queue/logger
20:01:41,844 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/logger
20:01:41,845 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
20:01:41,845 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-13) trying to deploy queue jms.queue.demoQ
20:01:41,847 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/demoQ
20:01:41,849 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/queue/demoQ
20:01:41,850 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-15) trying to deploy queue jms.topic.testTopic
20:01:41,850 INFO  [org.jboss.as.deployment.connector] (MSC service thread 1-16) JBAS010406: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
20:01:41,863 INFO  [org.hornetq.ra.HornetQResourceAdapter] (MSC service thread 1-16) HornetQ resource adaptor started
20:01:41,863 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-16) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatorhornetq-ra
20:01:41,865 INFO  [org.jboss.as.deployment.connector] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010401: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
20:01:41,895 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/test
20:01:41,895 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/topic/test
20:01:41,904 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS018559: Deployed "postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar"
20:01:41,916 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar")]) - failure description: "JBAS014803: Duplicate resource [(\"deployment\" => \"postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar\")]"
20:01:41,936 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => "JBAS014803: Duplicate resource [(\"deployment\" => \"postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar\")]"}}
20:01:41,937 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) undefined
20:01:42,148 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
20:01:42,149 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 2492ms - Started 199 of 281 services (80 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Error (Snapped)

```
20:01:41,916 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar")]) - failure description: "JBAS014803: Duplicate resource [(\"deployment\" => \"postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar\")]"
20:01:41,936 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => "JBAS014803: Duplicate resource [(\"deployment\" => \"postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar\")]"}}
20:01:41,937 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) undefined
```

I am getting this error, I am running the jboss by running,

```
./standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's pretty clear here: **Duplicate resource...postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar**. You have two copies of that jar on the classpath or in the */common/lib* folder

Answer (score 22):

I think this problem happened when I was manually deploying, while also using the Eclipse deployment tool.  I found I lost the ability to launch the server, which means I could not access the admin console.

1. Go to `<myJBossDirectory>\standalone\configuration`
2. Open "standalone.xml"
3. At the end of the XML file delete the node, `<deployments><deployment></deployment></deployments>` 
   (This should erase all of the deployments you may have done manually)
4. Try restarting the server, "standalone.sh" or "standalone.bat".

Comment: No such node in my standalone.xml - Wild Fly 8.1

Answer (score 10):

Edit file /standalone/configuration/standalone.xml.

Search for deployment-scanner and remove duplicate entries to the same folder.

I experienced this problem when I a added wildfly 8.1 server in eclipse using jbosstools.

Comment: I don't have any duplicates...just one `<deployment-scanner>`.

Comment: this worked for me as well. In my case I think the other entry was added by IntelliJ Idea.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, it turned out that I had a version deployed using the admin console.  When I removed it from there, the duplication error went away.

Answer (score 0):

For future searchers: kolossus is right, as I found out. A quick search showed that I had copied my EAR file to two different folders (./deploy and ./deploy/comp/prod/). Deleting the unintended copy fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check file with same name not exists in below locations
1.  /standalone/deployments
2.  //deployments

Answer (score 0):

`ls $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments/` showed i had two `knob.yml` entries, deleted them and didn't encounter this error on subsequent deploy

Answer (score 0):

What mentioned earlier do not apply to my case. What I did that fixed the issue: delete everything under the ./tmp folder created by JBoss.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all ear/war from jboss-eap-6.4\standalone\deployments folder