# Why JBoss doesn't deploy first artefact by IDEA

Tags: deployment, jboss, ear

My problem is that from time to time JBoss doesn't want deploy **1st artifact** (ear) on the list, but after restarting or redeploying all is OK.
   This problem happens not only with my machine, so maybe someone knows cause of this? 
It takes time to redeploy all my artifacts because IDEA sometimes don't want to deploy only one and begins to make whole project without maven.

P.S. It seems like problem with IDEA deployment tool -  I got this string in console

```
...
Detected server admin port: 9999
  Artifact int-bus-nsi-service-ear:ear: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Detected server http port: 8080
  Artifact int-bus-ppa-service-ear:ear: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
  Artifact nsi-rest:war: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
  Artifact ppa-rest:war: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
  Artifact ppa-service-ear:ear: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
  Artifact nsi-service-ear:ear: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:35251', transport: 'socket'
  INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.0.Final-redhat-2
  INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.0.4.GA-redhat-1
  INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14) starting
  INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
...
```

Then deployment starts...

```
  ...
  INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "eventjournal.war" (runtime-name: "eventjournal.war")
  INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "int-bus-nsi-service-ear.ear" (runtime-name: "int-bus-nsi-service-ear.ear")
  INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/hcsebds]
  ...
```

After binding to data sources:

```
...
INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment int-bus-nsi-service-impl.jar
INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-7) JNDI bindings for session bean named NsiFacade in deployment unit subdeployment "int-bus-nsi-service-impl.jar" of deployment "int-bus-nsi-service-ear.ear" are as follows:

    java:global/int-bus-nsi-service-ear/int-bus-nsi-service-impl/NsiFacade!ru.lanit.hcs.intbus.nsi.api.NsiFacade
    java:app/int-bus-nsi-service-impl/NsiFacade!ru.lanit.hcs.intbus.nsi.api.NsiFacade
    java:module/NsiFacade!ru.lanit.hcs.intbus.nsi.api.NsiFacade
...

  ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "int-bus-nsi-service-ear.ear")]) - failure description: "JBAS014803: Duplicate resource [(\"deployment\" => \"int-bus-nsi-service-ear.ear\")]"
 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment int-bus-nsi-service-ear.ear
 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment null (runtime-name: int-bus-nsi-service-impl.jar) in 592ms
 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
  ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14) started (with errors) in 71396ms - Started 4397 of 4548 services (19 services failed or missing dependencies, 103 services are passive or on-demand)
 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment int-bus-nsi-service-ear.ear (runtime-name: int-bus-nsi-service-ear.ear) in 1250ms
 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS018558: Undeployed "int-bus-nsi-service-ear.ear" (runtime-name: "int-bus-nsi-service-ear.ear")
 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment int-bus-ppa-service-ear.ear
 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment null (runtime-name: int-bus-ppa-service-impl.jar) in 126ms
Artifact int-bus-nsi-service-ear:ear: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
Artifact int-bus-nsi-service-ear:ear: java.lang.Exception: JBAS014803: Duplicate resource [("deployment" => "int-bus-nsi-service-ear.ear")]
...
```

Comment: It seems I've found answer -  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24718089/4353841